# Using if any in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have the Matlab code below:

```
// if any(c(:,part) == cent)
```

I used the java code below :

```
double [][] cnt = {{1.1, 2.1}, {2.4, 4.5}};
double [][] c = {{1.1, 2.1}, {2.4, 4.5}, {3.1, 4.2}, {6.1, 5.5}};
for (int ii=0; ii < D.length; ii++){
    for (int jj = 0; jj < part; jj++){
        if (Arrays.equals(c[ii][jj], cnt) {
            System.out.print(c);
            double [ii][jj] c1 = c;
        }
    }
}
```

The code fails with the following error:

```
no suitable method for equal double, double[][].
```

Comment: For those of us who don't know Matlab, what is the objective of your code?  What do you actually want to determine?

Comment: @Jim , the objective is to find the element  in c which is equal to cnt value and store them in array.

Comment: There is no "element in c which is equal to cnt value".  Do you mean "Find elements in `c` (i.e. arrays) which match an element in `cnt`"?  For your example the elements in `c` that also exist in `cnt` are `{1.1, 2.1}` and `{2.4, 4.5}`.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @Jim, I update the data , yes find cnt which is array : {{ 1.1 , 2.1},{2.4,4.5}};  in c which is :          c = {{ 1.1 , 2.1},{2.4,4.5}, {3.1, 4.2},{ 6.1, 5.5}};

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.equals` is a method to compare Arrays as the name suggest,

but you are doing:

```
if (Arrays.equals(c[ii][jj],cnt) {
```

which is comparing the element at index **[ii][jj]** of the array **c** against **cnt**.